# With PHP, is it possible for list() to append onto arrays?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that I'm iterating through. I'm trying to have a variable "exploded" into pieces and then appended onto respective arrays using list(), like so:

```
list($a[], $b[], $c[]) = explode(':', $loop);
```

Can list() not do this? It errors with

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

I suppose that I could just use temp variables in list(), and then append them onto the respective arrays afterward, like so:

```
foreach($array as $loop) {
    list($a1, $b2, $c3) = explode(':', $loop);

    $a[] = $a1;
    $b[] = $b2;
    $c[] = $c3;
}
```

Is this there a better/more efficient way to do this (such as entirely using list())?

Comment: If I initialize `$a,$b,$c` as arrays, the first line actually works for me. I _can_ actually `list()` right into array elems with `[]`.  What is in `$array` in your code?

Comment: Ah, k. I didn't realize it, but I am only first initializing `$a,$b,$c` inside `list()`. (Just for reference, is that a programming no-no?). `$array` is an array with 10-20 strings (the strings are the latter half of urls, like `'/questions/12886947/'`)

Comment: @Coldblackice: Works for me: http://codepad.org/SsaYK0OP - Your problem is that you do not first initialize the variables there, you re-use one of them, that is why you see the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct needs a valid variable expression, like with an array and index:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $loop) {
    list($a[$i], $b[$i], $c[$i]) = explode(':', $loop);
}
```

Then everything works. [Demo](http://codepad.org/uyVoCVUT).

Also if that are actually arrays, it works, too:

```
$a = $b = $c = array();

foreach ($array as $loop) {
    list($a[], $b[], $c[]) = explode(':', $loop);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/04VvcYTc)

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZAc5aZ  Works for me if they're initialized (Oh sorry, you just added that...)

Comment: They don't have to if you add the index @Michael Berkowski

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: You can even skip the initialization if those are unset. Problem for OP is that one of those is being re-used. See http://codepad.org/SsaYK0OP

Comment: Would one way be more "professional" than the other? I.e., is it better programming habit/etiquette to initialize something beforehand? I wonder if it's perhaps lazy on my part to first-initialize something inside `list()`.

Comment: @Coldblackice: Well in your case - lazy or not aside - you just made a mistake. Initializing might prevent you that if your own coding rules help you to improve your code. However, I'd say it's more important to understand the error message properly, because that will help you more. PHP assumed substring access, so you could smell  that one of those "I want them to be arrays" was actually a string. Happen with variable re-use. Do not do variable-reuse is more professional here.

Comment: @hakre .. Good to see you today ... :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can .. Just add the `Index` without Initialize the variables

```
list($a[0], $b[0], $c[0]) = explode(":","A:B:C") ;
var_dump($a,$b,$c);
```

Or Initialize the variables

```
$a = $b = $c = array();
list($a[], $b[], $c[]) = explode(":","A:B:C") ;
var_dump($a,$b,$c);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'A' (length=1)
array
  0 => string 'B' (length=1)
array
  0 => string 'C' (length=1)
```

Comment: So in your second example (initializing the variables), is it necessary to add `[]` after each variable in `list()`? Or will PHP know to append onto the arrays?

Comment: @Coldblackice .. sorry i missed that